# Spark insert to HBase slow

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am inserting to HBase using Spark but it's slow. For 60,000 records it takes 2-3mins. I have about 10 million records to save.

```
object WriteToHbase extends Serializable {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val csvRows: RDD[Array[String] = ...
        val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        val usersRDD = csvRows.map(row => {
            new UserTable(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(9), row(10), row(11))
        })
        processUsers(sc: SparkContext, usersRDD, dateFormatter)
    })
}

def processUsers(sc: SparkContext, usersRDD: RDD[UserTable], dateFormatter: DateTimeFormatter): Unit = {

    usersRDD.foreachPartition(part => {
        val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
        val table = new HTable(conf, tablename)

        part.foreach(userRow => {
            val id = userRow.id
            val name = userRow.name
            val date1 = dateFormatter.parseDateTime(userRow.date1)
            val hRow = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(id))
            hRow.add(cf, q, Bytes.toBytes(date1))
            hRow.add(cf, q, Bytes.toBytes(name))
            ...
            table.put(hRow)
        })
        table.flushCommits()
        table.close()
    })
}
```

I am using this in spark-submit:

```
--num-executors 2 --driver-memory 2G --executor-memory 2G --executor-cores 2
```

Answer (score 3):

It's slow because the implementation doesn't leverage the proximity of the data; the piece of Spark RDD in a server may be transferred to a HBase RegionServer running on another server.

Currently there is no Spark's RRD operation to use HBase data store in efficient manner.

Comment: If you're reading from HBase, Spark actually is able to use data locality.

Answer (score 0):

There is a batch api in Htable, you can try to send put requests as 100-500 put packets.I think it can speed up you a little. It returns individual result for every operation, so you can check failed puts if you want.

```
public void batch(List<? extends Row> actions, Object[] results)
```

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#batch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object[]%29

Answer (score 0):

You have to look on the approach where you can **distribute** your incoming data in to the **Spark** Job. In your current approach of **foreachPartition** instead you have to look on Transformations like map, mapToPair as well. You need to evaluate your whole **DAG lifecycle** and where you can save more time.

After that based on the Parallelism achieved you can call **saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset** Action of Spark to write inside HBase more fast and parallel. Like:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> yourFinalRDD = yourRDD.<SparkTransformation>{()};    
yourFinalRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(yourHBaseConfiguration);
```

Note: Where **yourHBaseConfiguration** will be a singleton and will be single object on an Executor node to share between the Tasks

Kindly let me know if this Pseudo-code doesn't work for you or find any difficulty on the same.